# Any way to keep a chicken baked in the oven dry?

Tags: chicken

My SO has a big thing with the textures of what she eats. And a 'moist' chicken is definitely something that is not on her OK list.

So when baking a whole chicken in the oven, is there tips and tricks to have a chicken that is NOT moist?

Comment: ...over cook it?

Comment: Would there be good temps to over cook it to so its less dry but not a wood plank?

Answer (score 4):

Just follow any recipe for oven baked chicken and add roughly 15 to 30 min of extra cooking time. By then, the internal temperature of the meat will definitely have exceeded 66°C/150° F, after which the breast meat begins to dry out (see seriouseats link below).

[Seriouseats guide to spatchcocking chicken](https://www.seriouseats.com/butterflied-roasted-chicken-with-quick-jus-recipe) could give you an idea on how to *purpusefully* overcook a chicken by *not* spatchcocking it. This way, the breast will likely be overcooked, and thus dry, while the drumsticks should be "perfect" (by the credo that dry chicken = not perfect).

This way, your SO could enjoy a dry breast, while you could eat juicy drumsticks and thighs.